# .NET Core MVC Startup equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am wondering is, since I would like to implement dependency injection container for my web application (MVC) controllers. In .NET Core framework, I used to have a `Startup.cs` file inside the project which was used for adding transients and dependency injections to the container, also for `DbContext`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>();
        services.AddTransient<IGetBooksCommand, EfGetBooksCommand>();
    }
```

I would like to know how could I achieve this in the full .NET Framework.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net core Mvc supports built in dependency injection and it is capable of injecting dependencies in the controllers. So dependency registered as below can be used in controller

```
services.AddTransient<IGetBooksCommand, EfGetBooksCommand>();
```

However built in dependency injection functionality can be replaced by more mature DI frameworks. And that is very simple as below is the example for using Autofac

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Populate(services);
    builder.RegisterType<EfGetBooksCommand>().As<IGetBooksCommand>();
    var container = builder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

ConfigureServices method now returns IServiceProvider instead of void. And dependencies will now be resolved using Autofac.

ref :

[Dependency injection into controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

[.Net Core Dependency Injection](https://stackify.com/net-core-dependency-injection/)

Answer (score 2):

Prior to .Net Core, there is no built-in support for dependency injection the only way to get it was through the use of third-party frameworks such as [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/), [Unity](http://unitycontainer.org/), [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) ..etc

You can check any of these frameworks and use them in your project.

Comment: Or writing your own (not recommending, but plausible)